# Leibniz formula for Pi with a given accuracy

Tags: kotlin, math

I was asked to calculate the Pi number using the Leibniz formula for Pi with a given accuracy (`eps`).

The formula looks like this:

[image]

Initially, I wrote the following code:

```
fun main() {
    val eps = 0.005
    var n = 2
    var r = row(n) // current row
    var r0 = row(n-1)
    var s = r0 + r
    
    while (Math.abs(r) > eps) {
        n++
        r = row(n)
        s += r
    }
    println(r.toString() + " <-- Leibniz(" + n.toString() + ")")
    println(Math.abs(s*4).toString() + " <-- our evaluation with eps")
    println(Math.PI.toString() + " <-- real Pi")
    println((Math.abs(s*4)) in (Math.PI-eps..Math.PI+eps))
}

fun row(n: Int) = ((Math.pow(-1.0, n.toDouble()))/(2*n-1))
```

Then I found out that it doesn't work correctly, because
`println((Math.abs(s*4)) in (Math.PI-eps..Math.PI+eps))` printed `false`.

I went deeper, made a debug, and realised that if went with 
`while (Math.abs(r) > eps/2)` 
over 
`while (Math.abs(r) > eps)`
 everything works fine.

Could someone please provide any explanation on what I did wrong or why I have to divide `eps` by 2 if that is correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each term `r_i` in that series is summed up to PI with a factor of 4 because `sum(r_0, .., r_n) = PI/4`. So of course, when you stop at the first `r_i <= eps` that only means that `sum(r_0, ..., r_(i-1))` has an accuray of `eps`, ie it is somewhere in between `[PI/4 - eps/2, PI/4 + eps/2]`. But PI it self is `4*sum` thus the accuracy is of course `4*eps` ie the approximation lies somewhere inbetween `[PI-2*eps ,PI+2*eps]`

For your value of `eps = 0.005`:

- The first `r_100 = 0.00497512...` is the first `r <= eps`
- `sum(r0, ..., r_99) = 0.782829`, so PI at that point would be approximated as `3.1315929`

**EDIT**

Also you are actually calculating `-PI` because are flipping the sign of each term in the series. So what you call `r0` in your code (it should rather be called `r1` because it's the result of `row(1)`) is `-1` instead of `+1`

Answer (score 0):

When you check `Math.abs(r) > eps` you're looking at the size of the n-th element of the series.

The distance of your current approximation from `PI` is the sum of all the terms in the series after that one.

As far as I know the relationship between the size of the n-th element of a convergent series and how good of an approximation you have depends on the specific series you are summing.